# SDL2 engine base implementation

Tags: c++, sdl2

I would like a little help with the implementation of my SDL2 engine. It's actually not a real engine nor does it strive to be but I don't have a better word to describe it.

The purpose of this project is to serve as a base for other things to be built on, like a visualization of fractals for example, so i would like to make it as optimal as possible.

For now it just creates a window, renderer and handles basic input handling. Before I move on with it I would like to iron out any kinks there might be so any improvement suggestion would come in handy, especially when it comes to performance and future upgradability.

engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H
#pragma once

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "window.hpp"
#include "renderer.hpp"

class Engine
{
private:
 bool running;

public:
 Window window;
 Renderer renderer;

 Engine();

 ~Engine();

 //Handles input
 void handleInput();
 //draws things onto the screen
 void draw();

 bool isRunning();

};

#endif
```

engine.cpp

```
#include "engine.h"

Engine::Engine(): window( 640, 480 ), renderer( window.getWindow() )
{
  if( window.getWindow() == NULL )
  {
    printf("Window could not be created. \n" );
    running = false;
  }
  else
  {

    if( renderer.getRenderer() == NULL )
    {
      printf("Renderer could not be created. \n" );
      running = false;
    }

    running = true;
    printf("Engine has been started successfuly \n" );
  }
}

Engine::~Engine()
{
  running = false;

  window.close();
  renderer.close();
}

void Engine::handleInput()
{
  SDL_Event event;

  while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) != 0 )
  {
    if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
    {
      window.close();
    }
  }
}

void Engine::draw()
{
  SDL_RenderClear( renderer.getRenderer() );

  SDL_RenderPresent( renderer.getRenderer() );
}

bool Engine::isRunning()
{
  return window.isOpen() && renderer.isCreated() && running;
}
```

window.hpp

```
#ifndef WIDNOW_H
#define WINDOW_H
#pragma once

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Window
{
private:
  const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 0;
  const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 0;
  bool open = false;

  //Window we'll render to
  SDL_Window* mWindow = NULL;

public:
  Window();

  //Consturctor to initialize window
  Window( int SCREEN_WIDTH, int SCREEN_HEIGHT );

  ~Window();

  void close();

  bool isOpen();

  SDL_Window* getWindow();
};

#endif
```

window.cpp

```
#include "window.hpp"

Window::Window()
{

}

//Initialize SDL and create a window
Window::Window( int SCREEN_HEIGHT, int SCREEN_WIDTH ): SCREEN_WIDTH(SCREEN_WIDTH), SCREEN_HEIGHT( SCREEN_HEIGHT)
{
  //If SDL video was not initialize
  if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 )
  {
    printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    open = false;
  }
  else
  {
    //Create window
    mWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "Window class", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

    //If the window was not created
    if( mWindow == NULL )
    {
      printf( "Could not create window. SDL error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
      open = false;
    }
      //Set the open flag to true after the operation completed successfuly
      open = true;
      printf("Window was created successfuly.\n" );
  }
}

void Window::close()
{
    open = false;

    SDL_DestroyWindow( mWindow );
    mWindow = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}

Window::~Window()
{
  printf("Window destructor was called \n" );

  close();
}


bool Window::isOpen()
{
  return open;
}

SDL_Window* Window::getWindow()
{
  return mWindow;
}
```

renderer.hpp

```
#ifndef RENDERER_H
#define RENDERER_H
#pragma once

#include "window.hpp"

class Renderer : public Window
{
private:
  bool created = false;

  SDL_Renderer* mRenderer = NULL;
public:

  Renderer();
  Renderer( SDL_Window* window );
  ~Renderer();

  void close();

  bool isCreated();

  SDL_Renderer* getRenderer();

};

#endif
```

renderer.cpp

```
#include "renderer.hpp"

Renderer::Renderer()
{

}

Renderer::Renderer( SDL_Window* window )
{
  //create the renderer
  mRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );

  //if the rendere was not created
  if( mRenderer == NULL )
  {
    printf("Renderer could not be created. SDL error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    created = false;
  }
  else
  {
    //Set the render draw color to white
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( mRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );

    created = true;

    printf("Renderer was created successfuly \n" );
  }
}

Renderer::~Renderer()
{
  printf("Renderer desturctor was called \n" );

  close();
}


bool Renderer::isCreated()
{
  return created;
}


void Renderer::close()
{
  SDL_DestroyRenderer( mRenderer );
  mRenderer = NULL;
}

SDL_Renderer* Renderer::getRenderer()
{
  return mRenderer;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "engine.h"


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Engine engine;

  while( engine.isRunning() )
  {
    engine.handleInput();
    engine.draw();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: Note that general "best practices" questions are explicitly off-topic here, so the title edit is important to prevent your question being closed!

Comment: Have you tested this engine? Does it currently produce satisfactory output?

Comment: @Mast
♦ The engine does create a window and renderer and handles exiting the program. I have made some improvements with the help of suggestions from here. There is also a bug where multiple instances of the window are created when inheriting from the engine class. I fixed it by implementing the window and renderer as singletons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Engine:

```
Engine::Engine(): window( 640, 480 ), renderer( window.getWindow() )
```

We should probably set the `running` variable to `false` here to prevent accidents. (Or we could do so in the member variable declaration like the other classes do).

```
if( window.getWindow() == NULL )
{
  printf("Window could not be created. \n" );
  running = false;
}
```

I think it's reasonable to throw an exception if something so fundamental goes wrong. It's simpler to avoid the complexity of trying to carry on running the program in an abnormal state.

Note that this specific check would then be unnecessary. We could throw the exception from the `Window` constructor, and have it propagate upwards. We could do the same in the `Renderer` constructor.

---

Consider adding an `Engine::run()` function to hold the main loop, so that `main` can just call `engine.run()`. But the best way of doing things rather depends on how you add the functionality for your visualization, and how it interacts with `Engine`. (i.e. will you put that code inside `Engine`, or will you pass the `Engine` to that code?)

---

### Window:

```
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 0;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 0;
```

I don't think these should be `const`. We'll probably need to make the window resizeable at some point.

More importantly, we shouldn't store these variables at all. SDL will handle resizing our window, and we don't want to have to keep our own variables up to date. We should simply use `SDL_GetWindowSize` when we need the current window size.

---

```
bool open = false;
```

I don't think we need this variable. We can check that `mWindow` is not `nullptr` to see if the window is open.

---

```
if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 )
...
SDL_Quit();
```

I'm not sure these should be inside the `Window` class, since SDL handles more than just the windowing. We also need a valid SDL context for rendering, audio, input etc. So perhaps SDL init and shutdown could be put in a separate `SDLContext` class that's created before the window.

---

### Renderer:

```
bool created = false;
SDL_Renderer* mRenderer = NULL;
```

As with `Window::open`, we don't need the `created` flag. We can check `mRenderer`.

Comment: You can, for example, have two windows, and then the asker's code initializes SDL twice.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the C macro `NULL`.  C++ has a real null pointer named `nullptr`.  Meanwhile, don't explicitly compare against `nullptr`, but rather use the convert-to-boolean truth value of the pointer (this is important when you use smart pointers, and is idiomatic for any pointer type).  That is, write:

`if(p)   // NOT if(p!=nullptr)`
`if(!q)  // NOT if(q==nullptr)`

`ENGINE_H` is not unique enough to not clash with anything else.  Personally I leave off the guards and use `#pragma once` and would use an automated program to put in guards *if* I ever found a platform that needed them.  Use a GUID-based identifier if you must have a guard.

You're using `printf` for logging, but never included the proper header for that.  Consider using a standard error for such logging rather than standard output, and don't use `printf` because at some point you'll want to show class types and strings in particular.  I really don't want to use a function that will compile without complaint but crash if it's passed an argument that it can't handle, *especially* on an error pathway that doesn't get tested in a normal run.

---

```
Renderer::Renderer()
{

}
```

Don't explicitly write empty-bodied constructors or destructors!  Here, put
`Renderer() = default;` in the class definition.

---

```
bool Renderer::isCreated()
{
  return created;
}
```

Put this inline in the class definition, and **declare the function as `const`**.

Same with `isOpen` and other *accessors*.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. By the conver-to-bool value do you mean explicitly casting the `nullptr` to `bool`, because that throws an error on my machine,  or is that the same as something like `return mWindow != nullptr`.

Comment: @AsmirZukić I clarified with an example.  No, do not explicitly cast anything.

Answer (score 0):

Its not much but note that you have a spelling mistake in windows.hpp

//Consturctor to initialize window

should be

//Constructor to initialize window